# Which Ad Networks Allow Rewarded Videos When Paying Out Real Money to Users?

Tags: android, ios, admob, facebook-ads-api

Google Admob specifies in [their terms](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7313578?hl=en):

"Rewarded ads must not be placed in apps that offer, as a reward or otherwise, monetary compensation or offers that can be converted into monetary compensation (including gift cards, discounts for physical goods or services, and cryptocurrencies)."

I am trying to determine if this means, that in any circumstance, you cannot pay out real money to users, in your app, for completing certain activities, if using rewarded videos.

Is this understanding correct? Do certain Ad Networks allow this placement or is it strictly prohibited across the board?

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert on this, but I don't believe any ad networks allow this.

Most ad networks would not want you to make money from your users also making money. If you kind of see what I'm saying, rewarded ad videos are for in-game or in-app rewards that users can trade time to gain rewards. Both parties benefit because the user gains a reward in his game or app while the developer makes money from conversions and the advertising company gains popularity for their service.

However, if both parties are making money, something can't be right and I believe most ad networks know this to be true.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How are these apps getting away with it? Lucky Day Lotto:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.luckyday.app&hl=en_US

Money App:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=proxima.moneyapp.android

Cash Quiz:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cashquizz.cashquizz